# I am learning basic Python. I am not able to execute this code

Tags: python, floating-point

I am learning basic Python. I am not able to execute this code:

```
n=0
current_savings = 0.0
while current_savings<7500.0:
    current_savings = 1000.0 + (4/12/100*current_savings)
    print(current_savings)
    n = n+1
print(n)
```

What am I doing wrong? If I don't divide by 12 and 100, my code works.

Comment: Which result are you expecting? The value of `current_savings` converges on ~1003.35. (Why) is this not what you’re expecting?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Actually it's closer to 1003.34 (it's 1003.34448...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to update the value of current_savings after every iteration:

```
n=0
current_savings = 0.00
while current_savings<7500.0:
    current_savings = current_savings + (1000.0 + (4/12/100*current_savings))
    print(current_savings)
    n = n+1
print(n)
```

But what you are doing currently is assigning the value of the expression `1000.0 + (4/12/100*current_savings)` (i.e 1003.34) repeatedly to current_savings. You'll never arrive at the termination value of 7500.0 and this will cause your while loop to run infinitely since current_savings is always 1003.34.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going in an infinite loop.

```
n=0
current_savings = 0.0
while current_savings<7500.0:
    current_savings = 1000.0 + (4/12/100*current_savings)
    print(n,current_savings)
    n = n+1
    if n==5:
        break
```

As you can see in the following output:

```
0 1000.0
1 1003.3333333333334
2 1003.3444444444444
3 1003.3444814814815
4 1003.3444816049383
```